# Installing PL/Python2 on Ubuntu for PostgreSQL 12

Tags: python-2.7, postgresql-12, plpython

PL/Python, and specifically PL/Python 2, is a requirement for the MADlib extension - which appears to support Postgres 9.2+. I am using Postgres 12 on Ubuntu 20.04.
Unfortunately, while I have symlinked Python2.7 to be the target for generic `python`, and while I have managed to download and build MADlib, I still cannot enable it due to it requiring PL/Python2 (aka plpythonu, or plpython2u) - which is nowhere to be found in the repos, and all documentation is silent on the issue (despite claiming that Python 2 is the default version).

Is there any way to install it from another source despite it being unsupported?

Comment: Hi LanceRD I wonder if you have found a solution to this problem? I encountered the exact same!

Comment: @asterix, nope, unfortunately. Seems that since the deprecation of Python v2 Postgres has silently dropped support for it and moved on, while MADlib, being built primarily for Greenplum, remained (because Greenplum solidly rests on v2 and has remained so for years after deprecation. cool.)
What I ended up doing is instead calling statsmodels' implementations in PL/PythonU3 - since it seems MADlib is doing more or less the same - and processing the results in PL/SQL code. Luckily, with acceptable efficiency.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Well, I guess I'll have to hunt in the wild too and grapple with whatever python modules that seem fitting for the job. What a shame, what a shame.